# Android volley library - what is the use of getHeaders() & getParams()?

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I am a newbie to Android. I have studied Android volley library, and I have doubted in `getHeaders()` and `getParams()` because those two methods post values into webservice.

What is the difference on those methods, and what is the reason for using `getHeaders()`?

Comment: Study the structure of an HTTP message. Then you'll understand what those do

Answer (score 1):

**getParams():**

To `POST` values to the server, you can simply store the values in a `HashMap` as `key-value` pairs. Overriding the `getParams()` method allows you to build the `HashMap` and return the `object` to the Volley `request` for posting.

```
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("user", "Android");
        params.put("pass", "123456");

        return params;
   }
```

**getHeaders():**

If you need to add any `headers` to the `request`, you can override the `getHeaders()` method and build/return your `key-value` pairs in a `HashMap` there as well.

```
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

getHeaders() is the method you have to override to pass the headers of your request and getParams() is the same for POST/PUT requests params.